# Delphi how to getting directory of network drives faster

Tags: performance, delphi, networking, directory

I just discovered that some programs are very quick when getting/listing the directory of network drives, almost instantly. I am talking about programs like FreeComanderXE and DirectoryOpus here.

In my program it takes several seconds to do the same task. What can I do to improve the speed here.

This is my code for loading the directory in a thread:

```
procedure LoadDirThread.Execute;
var
  PIdx: Integer;
  b: Boolean;
  n: Integer;
  FName: string;
  Item: TXplorerItem;
  i: Integer;
  Path: String;
  SR: TSearchRec;
  SFI: TSHFileInfo;
  FData: TXplorerItem;
begin
  inherited;
  if not XPlorerLink.Loaded then
  begin
    Path := XPlorerLink.Path;
    PIdx := XPlorerLink.PathList.IndexOf(Path);
    if PIdx = -1 then
      PIdx := XPlorerLink.PathList.Add(Path);

    if FindFirst(Path + '*.*', faAnyFile - faHidden, SR) = 0 then
    begin
      repeat
        if (SR.Name <> '.') and (SR.Name <> '..') then
        begin
          if (SR.Attr and faDirectory <> 0) then
          begin
            FData := TXplorerItem.Create;
            FName := Path + SR.Name;
            SHGetFileInfo(PChar(FName), 0, SFI, SizeOf(SFI), SHGFI_DISPLAYNAME or
              SHGFI_TYPENAME);
            FData.FAttr:= SR.Attr;
            FData.Kind := xiDir;
            FData.Size := 0;
            FData.Caption := Strpas(SFI.szDisplayName);
            if FData.Caption = '' then
              FData.Caption := ChangeFileExt(SR.Name, '');
            FData.Name := SR.Name;
            FData.Modified := FileDateToDateTime(SR.Time);
            FData.ImgIdx := -1;
            n := XPlorerLink.InfoList.IndexOf(SFI.szTypeName);
            if n = -1 then
              n := XPlorerLink.InfoList.Add(SFI.szTypeName);
            FData.InfoIdx := n;
            FData.PathIdx := PIdx;
            XPlorerLink.Items.Add(FData);
          end
          else
          if (SR.Attr and faDirectory = 0) then
          begin
            FData := TXplorerItem.Create;
            FName := Path + SR.Name;
            SHGetFileInfo(PChar(FName), 0, SFI, SizeOf(SFI), SHGFI_DISPLAYNAME or
              SHGFI_TYPENAME);
            FData.FAttr:= SR.Attr;
            FData.Kind := xiFile;
            FData.Size := SR.Size;
            FData.Caption := Strpas(SFI.szDisplayName);
            if FData.Caption = '' then
              FData.Caption := ChangeFileExt(SR.Name, '');
            FData.Name := SR.Name;
            FData.Modified := FileDateToDateTime(SR.Time);
            FData.ImgIdx := -1;
            n := XPlorerLink.InfoList.IndexOf(SFI.szTypeName);
            if n = -1 then
              n := XPlorerLink.InfoList.Add(SFI.szTypeName);
            FData.InfoIdx := n;
            FData.PathIdx := PIdx;
            XPlorerLink.Items.Add(FData);
          end;
        end;
      until (FindNext(SR) <> 0) or Terminated;
      FindClose(SR);
    end;
  end;
  if not Terminated then
    PostMessage(frmMain.Handle, CM_UPDATEVIEW, -2, Integer(XPlorerLink));
end;
```

Comment: How about you strip out all the UI code and just focus on the `FindFirst/FindNext` code. When you've done that, time it and see how it performs. All the other stuff is just distracting.

Comment: Well I already tried that, not much of an improvement. It still takes several seconds more than other explorer.

Comment: As David suggested, you need to strip out all of the UI-related code from your question here. Expecting people to wade through code that isn't related to the issue you're trying to get help with isn't quite reasonable, and the extra clutter makes it hard to figure out how to help you. Reduce it to the smallest amount of code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Ken, well if it was a lot of code here I would agree but in this contest I think it is better to actually show what is going on in the loop. Just my two cent. If you could not see what was going on in the loop how would you be able to suggest anything...

Comment: yourself cast doubt on your interest on getting help by not following suggested actions.

Comment: Well I removed most of the gui code so I will say I did just as suggested... but we might see it differently. I do not see this as a big problem. Those who have something to say about the problem will manage to do so I have no doubt about it... even if there are some unshaved stuff in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to use the `IShellFolder` interface instead of the `Find...()` functions. Everything in the Windows Shell is internally represented by `IShellFolder`, `ITEMIDLIST`s, etc, even file system and network paths. When performance matters, use Windows' own native data. Windows Explorer uses `IShellFolder` and related interfaces for all of its main work.

Comment: Yes, I think that is the only way to get the speed up I want. I was hoping to avoid it but seems like I got no other options. Thanks for the suggestion. Now I need to refresh my memory about the shell stuff.

Comment: you accepted the answer, did you find much improvement? tell us!

Comment: I have not done the update yet, but I will post a testing demo on my blog later. Then you will be able to test yourself. I will add here or under the question when done. You can always check my blog.

Comment: The premise of this answer does seem wrong to me. "When performance matters,
use Windows' own native data." But FindFirstFile is also native and intended to be quick. Why would IShellFolder magically be so much faster?

Comment: The `Find...()` functions operate on filesystem paths. That would be native if they were accessing the local hard drive, but the OP's question has to do with accessing network folders instead.  That is not native data, but has to be presented by Windows in a way that is compatible with filesystem functions.  `IShellFolder` has to do that anyway, but at least it is done in a way that is more compatible with Windows' other internals, which I consider to be more "native".